# ASP .NET Add HtmlImage tag to body attribute from code behind

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, dynamic

We have got several asp .net web forms page with a body tag in it. I want to add an [HtmlImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlimage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) tag just before the body tag finishes for all those pages. So for example - after doing that the code should look like this:

```
<body>

<img class="imgClass" id="imgID" src="someSource">
</body>
```

And the c# class that I need to do this is not code behind of an aspx file. But it does extends the class [Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx). Can somebody tell as to how to do that? I know the jQuery way but not from C# code. Also this is a sort of common code that will be called when any aspx page loads so a general solution will be good. That is why we don't have any ID for body tag.

Comment: _... common code that will be called_  -> use a [`UserControl`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1739/User-controls-in-ASP-NET)

Comment: It's a C# code and yes can be added as an user control. But how to do that? That's the main part of the question (adding htmlimage from c# code to a body tag)

Comment: if this is a common code use it in your master page. or add this image tag in all the aspx pages.

Comment: See [a tutorial of Usercontrols](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1739/User-controls-in-ASP-NET)

Comment: I can't add it to an aspx page. It needs to be added from C# code. ASPX file cannot be touched. It's basically added dynamically.

Comment: Try using `this.Controls.AddAt(0, <imgControl>);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a panel inside your body and give it some id.

```
<body>
    <asp:Panel id="panel_holder" runat="server">
    </asp:Panel>
</body>
```

and then in code behind

```
        HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("img");
        div.Attributes.Add("src", "image_location");
        panel_holder.Controls.Add(div);
```

Comment: for adding a panel and inserting a image tag in it is waste of time and resources. so add directly the image tag and if you want to change the src change it directly modifying its attributes in the code behind.